# Remove inserted data from wrong dump file

Tags: mysql, dump

I often backup my mysql db.
But recently I have imported wrong dump file.
Is there any way to revert the situation?

BR,

Comment: import the right one?

Comment: But, The wrong dump file affects my whole data. I need to revert. I mean, need to delete the imported data from wrong dump file.

Comment: you can't revert. You can only use one dump. Some hiosters make Backups as well see if the have your data

Comment: The dump file contains insert statements. To reverse inserts you will need to delete the inserted records, identifying them by unique keys for each table. Are you having difficulties running the delete statements?

Comment: you can import the back into another table, and remove the data, but as i don't know if you can removed , you must first a complete vackup before trying this